# How to get data in Access VBA from a C# method that returns an object List

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm calling a C# WebService method called `getInterventions()` on a *VBA Access 2003* application through a custom DLL. The signature of this method is as follows:

```
List<Item> getInterventions(string, string, string, string, string, string)
```

**Item** is a custom defined class.

When I try to retrieve the result of `getInterventions()` on VBA Access code, it pops a VBA ***Runtime error 242 : object required***

The following is my code:

```
        Dim WsObject As Object
        Dim result As Object

        Set WsObject = CreateObject("Namespace1.Path.To.Class") 'This isn't the actual DLL path as I cannot share that
        
        'Set result = WsObject .getSingleIntervention("123, "0", "123456789", "") ' this works
        
         Set result = WsObject .getInterventions("", "", "123456789", "", "", "") 'this doesn't work
        
         If result Is Nothing Then
           'do some stuff
        Else
           'do some other stuff
        End If
```

`getSingleIntervention()` is a similar method which returns a single object rather than a list of objects. Returning the result of this method works without issues (see commented line). This proves that both the WS & DLL calls work. This method is defined as follows:

```
Item getSingleIntervention(string, string, string, string)
```

I have tested calling `getInterventions()` directly from the C# code via Visual Studio 2015 with the same parameters I'm passing in my VBA code and it worked. This proves that it's not an issue with parameters or the method content.

**My conclusion:**
I am guessing it's something to do with the fact that I can't simply store a C# List of objects into a VBA Object.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: VBA is not VB.Net. It does not support .Net so cannot deal with `List<>`. You say you are calling the Web Service via a custom c# DLL. Can you not alter the DLL to convert the List to an Array?

Comment: Try declaring `result As ArrayList`. In order to do that, please add a reference to `mscorlib.tlb` from "Framework version 3.5". In fact, I will post a piece of code able to automatically add the necessary reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, automatically add `mscorlib.tlb` reference, running the next code:

```
Sub addMscorlibRef() 'necessary to use ArrayList
  'Add a reference to 'Mscorlib.dll':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  If dir("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319", vbDirectory) = "" Then _
     MsgBox "You need to install ""Framework version 3.5"".": Exit Sub
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb"
   If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Mscorlib"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

Then try declaring `Dim result As ArrayList`.

The ArrayList is the same one that is used in C#. Then, **adapt the dll to use such an object**. As you deduced, no any object able to be used in VBA can receive the C# `list` object content.

Comment: Should this work instead?

            `Dim result` -----
            
            `Set result = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")` -----
            `result = MyObject.getInterventions("", "", "123456789", "", "", "")`

Comment: Also, the whole point of this is avoiding to have to edit the DLL because that won't be very convenient for our client. I'm not sure if that would be possible however.

Comment: @It will not make to much difference if you do not adapt the dll. It is early binding. I suggested the reference, only to have access to intellisense suggestions. The idea is that **there is no VBA object able to deal with the C# `list` object result**. At least, I do not know such one. I am afraid that the client will be less satisfied if the existing dll will not work. You will offer an update, changing the previous dll. But, didn't you check it before delivering it to the customer?

Comment: This wasn't a part of the initial specs which were checked. The client decided to change his mind during the testing phase and now we're trying to figure out a way to make it happen. Unfortunately, it seems like the only way to do this would be adding a new method for this purpous in the WebService which will require updating the DLL too. Inconvenient but it is what it is.

Thank you very much for your help.